# Compactness of given subsets of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Looking for some feedback for solutions to select exercises from a basic Analysis course. All comments welcome!

1. Determine whether or not each subset of $\mathbf{R}^2$ is compact.  Briefly justify your answers.

   - $A = \{(x, y)~ | ~ x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 4 \} - \{(x, y)~|~ x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 1 \}$

A  is not compact.  To be compact, a subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$ must be both bounded and closed.  $A$ is bounded, but the point $(1,0)$ prevents $A^{c}$ from being open. Hence, $A$ is not closed, so $A$ is not compact.

- $B =  \{(x, \sin x)~ |x \in \lbrack -2\pi, 2\pi \rbrack\} \cap \{(x, y)~|~ y\geq 0 \}$

B is compact.  B is bounded above and below, and is therefore bounded. $B^{c}$ is also open, making B closed.  Hence, B is compact.

2. Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact subsets of a metric space.  Prove that $X \cup Y$ is compact.

Let $U_{\infty}$ be an open cover for $A \cup B$. Then $U_{\infty}$ is an open cover for $A$ and for $B$.  Since $A$ is compact, the union of some finite subset of $U_{\infty}$  $\{U_{1}, \ldots ,U_{k}\}$ covers $A$.  Similarly, since $B$ is compact,  the union of some finite subset of $U_{\infty}$  $\{U_{k+1}, \ldots, U_{n}\}$ covers $B$.  Taking the union of both sets produces a finite sub cover  $\{U_{1}, \ldots ,U_{k}, U_{k+1}, \ldots, U_{n}\}$ for both $A$ and $B$.  Hence $A \cup B$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to justify the assertions you're making. "$(1,0)$ prevents $A^c$ from being open" is not a rigorous argument. *Why* does this point do this? ("every neighborhood of $(1,0)$ ... ")

What are bounds for $B$? (saying "from above and below" is too informal, expecially since this is a subset of the *plane*, i.e. what about "left and right"?) Why is $B^c$ open?

The last one (with $X$ and $Y$) looks good.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!  For better or worse, our instructor has only requested a brief justification of our answers, which, if past experience is a guide, means either providing a simple counterexample (as in a)) or showing you understand the definition of compactness (as in b)). But you're right, I should get into the habit of providing fully worked out arguments for even simple questions like these.

Comment: Ok, sure. Your claim for $A$ in this case might simply be "$(1,0)$ is not an interior point of $A^c$" and "$B$ is bounded" is probably enough as well. The claim "$B^c$ is open" is basically not justified at all though.